# The time zone ID 'Eastern Daylight Time' was not found on the local computer

Tags: c#, .net, google-maps, datetime, google-api

I am using the Google Map API and in response I am getting the Timezone name "Eastern Daylight Time".

However when I trying to call the following method:

```
TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Daylight Time")
```

I am getting error of "The time zone ID 'Eastern Daylight Time' was not found on the local computer.".

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/43544299/1841839